# JSON encode from PHP

Tags: php, json

i have a problem with my PHP code.
I can't encoding all my record in my DB
This is my PHP code:

```
$out = array();
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($res3)){
array_push($out, array( 'nomi_partecipanti' => $row3['nomi_partecipanti'], 'importo' => $row3['importo'], 'Stato' => $row3['options'] ));

    print(json_encode($out));

}
```

i want the output json to be something like that:

```
[{"nomi_partecipanti":alex,"importo":"100","Stato":"pagato"},{"nomi_partecipanti":mark,"importo":"300","Stato":"pagato"}]}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `print(json_encode($out))` returning right now?

Comment: Is the print of my JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put json_encode outside of your `while` loop

```
 $out = array();
    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($res3)){
    array_push($out, array( 'nomi_partecipanti' => $row3['nomi_partecipanti'], 'importo' => $row3['importo'], 'Stato' => $row3['options'] ));



    }

        echo json_encode($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your output outside the while

```
$out = array();
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($res3)){
    array_push($out, array( 'nomi_partecipanti' => $row3['nomi_partecipanti'], 'importo' => $row3['importo'], 'Stato' => $row3['options'] ));
}
print(json_encode($out));
```